# Call webservice directly from ViewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to implement webservice call in my `ViewModel`. I just need send data to server (POST request) and get response if it was successful or not. To execute http requests I'm using Volley library. According to the Android architecture guide:

> A naive implementation of the ViewModel could directly call the Webservice to fetch the data and assign it back to the user object. Even though it works, your app will be difficult to maintain as it grows.

Can I directly call web service from `ViewModel`, or I should use another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call webservice directly from ViewModel for more details you can visit below link :

https://blog.oozou.com/calling-web-service-with-android-architecture-component-8de864800a93

Comment: This link doesn't demonstrate how to call a web service directly from the view model, it uses a repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. U can make api calls from viewmodel.
Make sure u dont use volley for api calls because it needs a context.
And passing context outside view causes problems.

I have used [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for this. Retrofit does not need context hence can use it without worries.